How to create a specific/custom element in Adobe EDS via Document Authoring?
Wondering how to create a custom element such as a
divider <hr class="sl-divider hr" aria-hidden="true">
or component divider line (see image attached for example) from the website I'm trying to replicate for my client, via Adobe's Experience Cloud - Edge Delivery Services and specifically document authoring; which utilizes Google Drive/docs to create the component blocks (unlike AEM).
I tried simply adding the line within the doc file, like via doc insert options for shapes and such. But it didn't translate over to the preview (im using AEM Sidekick chrome extension for that).
Truthfully im still learning EDS, and didn't really find an adequate way to learn what kind of document authoring steps to follow in order to generate a horizontal column, component blocks, dividers as the one im trying to make and what not. If theres information or good resources I can find more on EDS about, please share as well.
